# One activity using buttons to work another service in another activity?

Tags: java, android

The title is poorly written so I'll try and expand on it here. So I have 2 activities, main and options. In main I have 2 buttons that work fine and do their job. I now want to move those buttons to the options activity. When I do so and click the button the app crashes.

Heres the options activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
    setWindowParams();


}
```

Heres the main activity

```
if (MainActivity.isServiceRunning(this, LockScreenService.class)){
        onOffToggleButton.setChecked(true);

    }else{

        onOffToggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    if(!isNotificationServiceEnabled() || !onOffNotifButton.isChecked()) {
        onOffNotifButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

My ideal goal is get the main activity buttons into the options activity to be something like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
    setWindowParams();
    if (MainActivity.isServiceRunning(this, LockScreenService.class)){
        onOffToggleButton.setChecked(true);

    }else{

        onOffToggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    if(!isNotificationServiceEnabled() || !onOffNotifButton.isChecked()) {
        onOffNotifButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with this.

```
public void settingsClick(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, OptionsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

This here is the options button to start the activity if it helps.

EDIT:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="322dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LockScreen"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_line"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/on_off_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding"
            android:text="Off/On"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/on_off_toggle_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
            android:checked="false"
            android:onClick="startLockScreenService"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_line"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding"
        android:text="Off/On"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/on_offnotif_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector2"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Despite the title and all the code being mainly useless without the stacktrace of the crash, have you looked at the error of the crash? Also, when 'moving the buttons', did you also moved them in the xml layouts? And can their ids be found?

Comment: In the office I can't use the emulator so I have to build an APK to test so won't have a stacktrace. I tried at home but my android is not acting up, I'll have to have another look when I get home again tonight. The buttons are exact same in both layouts aswell.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving the buttons"? How do your xml files for each activity look like?

Comment: You can use a plugged in device like the emulator and get a stacktrace on crash…

Comment: You can deploy the debugging apk directly from Studio into any device, and read the stacktrace in the Studio's monitor (logcat) as well. Also, make sure your buttons, when created on different pages, would have different ids, otherwise they will remember the other's page buttons state, if any.

Comment: My phone doesn't work with developer mode for some reason, I've spent time trying to fix it before but could never get it working, I'll have to wait til I'm home I guess to check the stacktrace. Also VT-x is disabled in bios if that means I can't use emulator on my device, but I doubt it.

Comment: Yeah my phoen doesn't even havea  driver available for the ADB